# Save and reuse a design in a different PSD file

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Say I create an arrow with drop shadow and I want to save it and re-use it in another PSD file.

Is there a way to save the arrow in Photoshop to do this?

Comment: **1.** You could save the arrow in a `psd` ( or any supported file format if you don't care about flattening it ) and place it into the other document. **2.** PS CC has "Place linked" feature. When you edit the linked content, it will be updated in each document. **3.** You could select the layers, right click one of them and select `Duplicate layers..`. **4.** There is this plugin http://pixeldropr.com which lets you save graphic elements so that you can reuse them later. Sadly it doesn't do dynamic linking, it's pretty much like a graphic library within photoshop.

Comment: @joonas: your point 2 "updated in each document" sounds like the opposite of "doesn't do dynamic linking". Can you clarify?

Comment: @horatio These are all separate methods for doing it, not a workflow. "Place linked" works pretty much exactly like the linking in illustrator and indesign does.

Comment: Is this new? Illustrator recognizes updates to the file, but in older versions of Photoshop, editing the placed file separately cannot be updated in the document the image was placed in.

Comment: @horatio Yes it's relatively new. It's like a dream come true, really. http://blogs.adobe.com/richardcurtis/?p=2360 Although, funny enough, I haven't really really used it that much because I'm so used to not having it in photoshop.

Comment: This is good news.

Comment: @Joonas Why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @Yisela I don't like to post an answer when I'm not really sure what the op wants.  _Although I guess I have to admit that comments don't have enough space to explain these things properly and instead of giving half assed answers in a comment, I could've just asked what he really needs._

Answer (score 1):

If it is a shape you are talking about, you may "Define Custom Shape" for the shape itself and save the custom style as well.

An easy option is to save this, say, arrow with the shadow in a .PSB file and import it every time you wanna use it.

Answer (score 1):

Keep it as a PSD file.

If you have CC/CS6, just drag your element into the file - it will come in as a smart object you can double-click to access the layers.

Otherwise, you can easily include it in other PSD files by right clicking the layer(s) or your element (arrow) in the layers palette and selecting `Duplicate Layer`. Choose the intended PSD file you want it pasted in.

If you want to build a library of assets, you could keep them in layers/groups in a library.psd file. You can then duplicate your elements across to your working files as you go.